# Rails - how to make association between these models (not based on "id", but on "email")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys, associations, belongs-to

I have these models that obviously have more attributes, but for simplicity I kept them just like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subs, :foreign_key => :email, :class_name => "subs"
end
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the table `subscriptions`, there's a column called **email**. This column points to the table **users** where matches an email address of a single user (the column `email` is in both tables unique).

I would need to create an association between these two models based on the `email` value. But when I try to run this query (and to get all subscription for the currently sign in user):

```
<%= current_user.subs.inspect %>
```

I get this error message:

```
uninitialized constant User::subs
```

I'd like to ask you guys for helping me with this association.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> uninitialized constant User::subs

This code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subs, :foreign_key => :email, :class_name => "subs"
end
```

should be like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subs, :foreign_key => :email, :class_name => "Subscription"
end
```

When you are using a `class_name` option with the `associations`,it should point to the respected `model classname`(in your case it is `Subscription` not `subs`).Since there is no model with the classname `subs`,it throws that exception.

Comment: I've tried also this (what you're suggesting), but the output is `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` -> but in the table `subscriptions` is 10 records with this user's email.

Comment: I just checked what SQL query is generated: `SELECT subscriptions.* FROM subscriptions WHERE subscriptions.email = 1` -- which is obviously wrong, instead of `1` should be there an email address. How is that possible that in the query is ID instead of email address, if the foreign key is `email`?

Comment: @user984621 My post only answers the primary error you are getting i.e, `uninitialized constant User::subs`. At which line did you get this error `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subs, :foreign_key => :email, :class_name => "Subscription", :primary_key => :email
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :email, :class_name => "Subscription", :primary_key => :email
end
```

You have to set the correct Class name and also you have to set the primary key.